# How to open resource in new window in vaadin?

Tags: download, window, vaadin

I'm trying to generate a pdf in vaadin. My problem is that the generated pdf opens in the current window(browser tab). I tried:

```
 String filename = contentDataName + ".pdf";
    StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(source, filename, vaadinApplication);
    resource.getStream().setContentType("application/pdf");
    resource.getStream().setFileName(filename);
    resource.getStream().setParameter("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    resource.getStream().setParameter("Content-Length", Integer.toString(fopOutput.size()));
    resource.setCacheTime(5000);
    resource.setMIMEType("application/pdf");

    mainWindow.open(resource);
    mainWindow.open(resource, "_blank", true);
```

It doesn't work. What am i missing? I also tried

```
mainWindow.open(resource, "_blank");
```

Comment: I think there is a bug there because getStream() creates new stream every single time it is called.

Answer (score 3):

Following works for me (Vaadin 7)

```
    ClickListener getHelpButtonListener(final Button helpButton)
{
log.debug("+++++++++ setButtonListener ...++++++++++++++===.........");
final ClickListener helpButtonlistener = new ClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)
    {

    StreamSource source = new StreamSource()
    {
        public java.io.InputStream getStream()
        {
        try
        {
            String helpFilePath = basepath + "/datafiles/";
            File helpFile = new File(helpFilePath);
            FileInputStream helpFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(helpFile);
            return helpFileInputStream;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        }
    };
    String filename = basepath + "/datafiles/help.pdf";
    StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(source, filename);
    resource.setMIMEType("application/pdf");
    resource.getStream().setParameter("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(resource);
    opener.extend(helpButton);
    }

};
return helpButtonlistener;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work that way. Maybe this might be helpful: https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1572816?

Answer (score 0):

i did same job in my project, you can see my function below which is showing ".pdf" inside of Vaadin's Window. (ignore strange naming of objects and functions because its just peace of code of my project)

```
private void publishReport(final String path){
    StreamSource s = new StreamSource() {

        public java.io.InputStream getStream() {
            try {
                File f = new File(path);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                return fis;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(){


        @Override
        public InputStream getStream() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    };

    StreamResource r = new StreamResource(s, "appointmentScheduleDate.pdf", app);
    r.setCacheTime(-1);
    Embedded e = new Embedded();
    e.setSizeFull();
    e.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);

    r.setMIMEType("application/pdf");

    e.setSource(r);
    e.setHeight("650px");
    plaintReoprtWindow = new Window("Report");
    plaintReoprtWindow.center();
    plaintReoprtWindow.setModal(true);
    plaintReoprtWindow.setHeight("700px");
    plaintReoprtWindow.setWidth("900px");
    plaintReoprtWindow.addComponent(e);
    app.getMainWindow().addWindow(plaintReoprtWindow);
}
```